# Perl Hash/Array Implementation for Hadoop

Tags: arrays, perl, hadoop, hash

I am new to Perl and trying to figure out the best way to implement this, but unsure of syntax at the moment.

My script as of right now is reading a file off HDFS that contains key,value pairs out of a number of possibilities.

For example, let's say that I can have keys that range from A,B,C,D,E

The file I am reading from will be newline separated to look like:

```
A,50
C,30
```

In my script, I want to read the file and assign variables to the corresponding values, and if any variables do not exist, I want to assign them to a zero value.

So, by the end of the script, I want to have an output that prints like this:

```
A=50,B=0,C=30,D=0,E=0
```

With my limited knowledge in Perl, I was wondering how to set up the best loop to collect the information like this would be? I have functionality that reads the file, but nothing to collect the metrics into some kind of Array or Hash grouping.

Comment: Please show the code that you've written

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

my @keys = qw(A B C D E);     
open my $fh, '<', $filename_from_hdfs
   or die "$!";

my %mapping;
while ( my $line = readline($fh) ) {
   chomp($line);
   my ($key, $value) = split /,/, $line; 

   $mapping{$key} = $value; 
}

# zero out keys with no value
$mapping{$_} //= 0 foreach @keys; 

print join(',', map { "$_=$mapping{$_}" } sort keys %mapping), "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my %result;
#assign zero to all keys
for my $key ('A' .. 'E')
{
 $result{$key} = 0;
}
#open file, read each line one by one
#Split each read line from file in ($key, $value).
result{$key} = $value;

#After finishing reading the file, traverse %result and output key, values
```